# AJAX code not being executed

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Can someone please help me with this code by looking over it for something obvious? The problem seems to be that the embedded JavaScript code is not being executed and, therefore, the PHP code is also skipped. Both, the HTML and the PHP files are in the root directory.

html/js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery AJAX test form</title>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
  <!-- Contacts -->
  <div id="contacts">
    <div class="row"> 
      <!-- Alignment -->
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Some header message here</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <form name="contact" class="well" id="contact">
          <legend>Contact Form</legend>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" style="resize:none"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="success"> </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submit">Send</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="res">Reset</button>
          <br />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(function() {
    $("button#submit").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(){
                    alert("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
        $message= strip_tags($_POST['message']);
        echo "Name      =".$name."</br>";   
        echo "Email     =".$email."</br>";  
        echo "Message       =".$message."</br>";    
        echo "<span class=\"label label-info\" >your message has been submitted .. Thank you</span>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try `submit` event instead of `click` event

Comment: Not really sure, but it seems that you are just defining a function there, which is not called, so the code isn't loaded. Did you try replacing `$(function() {` with `$( document ).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: @cgf, `$(function()` is exactly equivalent to  `$( document ).ready(function()`.  See:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Tried all the above. It still does not want to access the js code. Thx for your input.

Answer (score 4):

The selector should be

> $('form#contact')

instead of

> $('form.contact')

As contact is an id.

Comment: Good catch. This, unfortunately, will not resolve the issue of that line not even being accessed. But thanks for your comment, since that will be one less thing for me to worry, once I take care of the main issue.

Comment: Are there errors in browser console? F12?

Comment: Nope. Am using firebug, and it does not throw any errors. The problem here is that I am totally new to ajax and the debugger, so I have some catching up to do here to at least know how to get around firebug.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your link is correct (`process.php`) and you have these two jquery library links (to be honest, I am not 100% if you need both, or only one or what, but I know between the two, the ajax works).

**You have no names in your form, only placeholders so there are no inputs. That is the real problem. Example:** `<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" />`

If it still doesn't work, you have a problem beyond what you are displaying in your code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $('#contact').serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                    $('#contacts').html(result);
                   // alert("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
     return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

process.php page:

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST);
// $_REQUEST['name'] has to be an input name in the form. Yours probably has $_REQUEST['Name'] (notice "name" vs "Name")
    if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
        $name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
        $email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['Email']);
        $message= strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
        echo "Name      =".$name."</br>";   
        echo "Email     =".$email."</br>";  
        echo "Message       =".$message."</br>";    
        echo "<span class=\"label label-info\" >your message has been submitted .. Thank you</span>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Great! One step closer. Adding the ajax header got the ajax code to be executed, but the php code is skipped. I added the 'name' tag to the html, but that did not do it. You got me closer to a solution. Thx a lot.

Comment: On your php page switch to $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

Comment: I think if you want to do $_POST you will probably have to do a json data type in your AJAX.

Comment: Also, it's important that you have a field named "name". Your `if` statement is dependent on there being a named field called "name". Best thing to do is on your `process.php` page put at the top of the page `print_r($_REQUEST)` and see when you submit that your page populates with a filled array.